# Yodlee REST API executeUserSearchRequest gives ExceptionOccured Error

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to get user transactions using `executeUserSearchRequest` from Yodlee REST API,

```
$postdata = array(
    'cobSessionToken'   =>  $cobSessionToken,
    'userSessionToken'  =>  $userSessionToken,
    'transactionSearchRequest.containerType' => 'all',
    'transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit' => 10,
    'transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit' => 1,
    'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber' => 1,
    'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber' => 10,
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId' => 1,
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName' =>'DataSearchService',
    'transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput' => true,
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType' => 'A');
```

and I am getting this error response:

> {"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"Exception
>   Occurred","referenceCode":"_8e50aecd-edd7-456f-acd5-d2d4236e2da2"}.

It does not specify what error or exception.

What went wrong, and what should I do to get user transactions using Yodlee REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it worked, its ALL_TRANSACTION. but the problem solved by enclosing all parameter values in single quotes. like this :

`$postdata = array(
    'cobSessionToken'   =>  $cobSessionToken,
    'userSessionToken'  =>  $userSessionToken,
    'transactionSearchRequest.containerType' => 'all',
    'transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit' => '10',
    'transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit' => '1',
    'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber' => '1',
    'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber' => '10',
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId' => '1',
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName' =>'DataSearchService',
    'transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput' => 'true',
    'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType' => 'ALL_TRANSACTION',

    );` 
By the way Thanks Apoorv

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the value you are passing as splitType`'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType' => 'A');`

It should be 'ALL_TRANSACTION' and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried ALL_TRANSACTIONS and ALL_TRANSACTION  but still getting same error `{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"Exception Occurred","referenceCode":"_6bcc54cb-9b08-49e2-ad5a-f898c343a6d4"}`.

Comment: My bad wrote 'ALL_TRANSACTIONS' it's 'ALL_TRANSACTION'. And yes it has to be enclosed by single quotes.